# Can we use past simple without giving the exact time?

Tags: past-tense, american-english, past-participles

Can we use past simple without giving the exact time. For example.

'I will tell you how I learned English through self-study.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infact it is misleading to  say that simple past is used always to talk about  things that indicate an exact time.

Your sententence   **I will  tell  you how I Iearned   Engish  through self study**    is correct

There are many instances where simpe past can be used  without referring to exact time.

> **1. columbus  discovered  America. (here time is implied)**
>
> **.2   I read  all of  shakespere' s  dramas** (  the exact time is not necesary  to tell.)

A.     **Why  are you crying?**

B      **My grand mother  beat  me.( here exact time is not necessary.**

Comment: What about "I will tell you how I have learned English through self-study."

Comment: @Abu Omar.Both the present perfect  and the simple past talk about the completion  of a task. But , Here  how I have learned may imply that  you are still learning..The first sentence does not tell whether you are self learning. It may suggest that you have reached  a certain  level well in the past